# orgmode - ipython output image not show in results

Tags: org-mode, ipython

I use below org code to draw a graph, but the graph not show on results block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :results drawer :session py2session
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(facecolor='white')
plt.hist(np.random.randn(500000), bins=100);
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x112819f90>
:END:
```

How can I draw the output graph from ipython to results block?

Answer (score 5):

Your example works perfectly in my setup.

**First** make sure ipython-ob is included in the babel-languages:
in my case:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
   (ipython . t)
   (ledger . t)
   (latex . t)
   (clojure .t)
   (shell .t)
    ))
```

**THEN**  display images online added to your init file:

```
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-display-inline-images 'append)
```

[image: The plot as it should be]]

Comment: Thanks, I use minimal config just the same as yours but it still doesn't work! I am using MacOsx and emacs version is 25.2, Not sure if any other config impact on this case!

Comment: Just to confirm... You aren't trying this in terminal, right?

Comment: Right, I run it in GUI, try it with -nw option also, behavior the same.